# Disabling a CellEditingTemplate programmatically in in a Silverlight DataGrid

Tags: silverlight, datagrid, celleditingtemplate

I have a Silverlight Datagrid, I'd like to make certain cells readonly programmatically.
Specifically I have a CellEditingTemplate, I'd like to turn the cell editing off or on depending on the value of CategoryTypeName (see the xmal below).

```
               <local:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Category" >
                    <local:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding CategoryTypeName}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </local:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <local:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                                <ComboBox 
                                  Width="90"
                                  x:Name="CategoryCombo"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding CategoryTypes}"
                                  DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                                  SelectionChanged="CategoryCombo_SelectionChanged"
                                  />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </local:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                </local:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Is there a way to do this?

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

One way to do it would be to have two controls overlapping each other in your `CellEditingTemplate` and only show the one you need.  Something like this

```
<local:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <ComboBox Visibility="{Binding CategoryTypeName, Converter={StaticResource ConverterToDecideIfItShouldBeEditable}}"
                      Width="90" x:Name="CategoryCombo"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding CategoryTypes}"
                      DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                      SelectionChanged="CategoryCombo_SelectionChanged" />
            <TextBox Text="{Binding CategoryTypeName}"  
                     Visibility="{Binding CategoryTypeName, Converter={StaticResource ConverterToDecideIfItShouldBeEditable},ConverterParameter=Inverse}"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</local:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
```

The key to this is the converter.  The second textbox gives a ConverterParameter as 'Inverse' which the converter than uses to return the opposite value.  Using this you can make the converter return `Visibility.Visible` for one of the controls and `Visibility.Collapsed` for the other control.

Comment: Still applies to WPF projects :) thumbs up.